# Z-test and Chi squared test producing different p-values

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

Given that I'm doing A/B testing for conversion rate on two groups, where group A has 6000 samples of which 90 are conversions, and group B has 4000 samples of which 80 are conversions. I want to know if group B has a statistically higher conversion rate.

I seemingly get a different answer depending on if I use a Z-test or Chi squared test and alpha = 0.5. Z-test returns a p-value of 0.0327 whereas Chi squared gives a p-value of 0.058.

The problem originates from https://towardsdatascience.com/the-art-of-a-b-testing-5a10c9bb70a4 , and trying it on my own I get the same values as in the article. The author attempts to explain the discrepancy by saying the Z-test doesn't take into account that the random variable of the difference of the mean is restricted to [-1, 1] but I don't really follow.

I was under the impression that these tests are equivalent for this type of problem, so why do they return different p-values?

Thanks.

Edit: As @BruceET suspected I was doing a two sided chi squared test, which obviously doesn't give the same p-value as the Z-test (or T-test to be more accurate..) for proportions. As was also pointed out I wasn't clear in how i was estimating the variances which was another problem. The method used in the article I followed was Welch's T-test (i.e. T-test without pooling variances). If I use the "exact" variance=mean*(1-mean)*(1/n_A + 1/n_B) where the mean is over both A and B, the p-value is 0.29, exactly half of that of the Chi squared test. I suspect I'll get something close to it if I use a pooled variance, but not tried it.

Comment: There are many versions the z test (continuity corrected and not, pooled or separate variances, etc.) and you give no clue which you're using. I'm not sure what kind of one-sided chi-squared test you may be using. // I browsed your link: for my taste it is diffuse, vague, and poorly written. I'm not saying it is wrong, only that I lack the motivation to make sense of it. // Two tests in R that I'd trust for this comparison are `fisher.test` (Fisher's exact test) and `prop.test`. Respective P-values are 0.35 and 0.346---essentially the same. Shown in my "Answer".

Comment: It's a Z-test of proportions, not continuity corrected. As for the variances I believe I was using separate variances, which may explain the differences I see. Not sure if it narrows it wn enough? Excuse the vagueness of the question, I've only been exposed to the one Z-test so didn't realize there was more to specify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize that this is not a direct answer to your question. However, using two fundamentally different procedures that I trust, I do not find any
conflict in the results. [My guess is that your 'z-test' may be one-sided and your 'chi-squared test' two-sided.]

Data:

```
conv = c(90,80)
size = c(6000, 4000)
nonc = size - conv
MAT = rbind(conv,nonc)

MAT
     [,1] [,2]
conv   90   80
nonc 5910 3920
```

One-sided [Fisher Exact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test) test:

```
fisher.test(MAT, alt="less")

         Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  MAT
p-value = 0.03543
alternative hypothesis: 
  true odds ratio is less than 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.00000 0.97505
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
 0.7462279
```

[One-sided test](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/software/dataplot/refman1/auxillar/binotest.htm) of $p_A = p_B$ against $p_A < p_B:$

```
prop.test(conv, size, alt="less")

        2-sample test for equality of proportions 
        with continuity correction

data:  conv out of size
X-squared = 3.2975, df = 1, p-value = 0.03469
alternative hypothesis: less
95 percent confidence interval:
 -1.0000000000 -0.0003285328    # Does not incl 0

sample estimates:
prop 1 prop 2 
 0.015  0.020
```

Two-sided chi-squared contingency test. (Irrelevant because you say you want a one-sided test, but this test is inherently two-sided.)

```
chisq.test(MAT, cor=F)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  MAT
X-squared = 3.5904, df = 1, p-value = 0.05811
```

Comment: Indeed I was doing a two sided chi squared test so I was comparing apples to oranges. But shouldn't the p-value of the Chi-squared test be double that of the other tests then? For the sake of the Z-test I was under the impression that there was mathematical equivalence, and there the difference feel higher than a rounding error (0.29 for Chi squared and 0.33 for Z).

Comment: After some googling I suspect the difference can be explained due to how I handled variances in the z test. Marking as solved, as the main source of confusion was the two sidedness of chi squared and there is another post that answers the question of equivalence (https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/173415/at-what-level-is-a-chi2-test-mathematically-identical-to-a-z-test-of-propo&ved=2ahUKEwjUv8md7dbsAhVQpYsKHfPmDoMQFjABegQIKxAB&usg=AOvVaw1FJWUOcx6gHUhEECVkFtJa). Thanks for the help @BruceET